# Visual Studio Form Designer blank when it isn't

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012

So I've been building this application and all of a sudden I can't see the designer for this application. The designer code is all there. I've tried reverting back. I've tried closing and reopening Visual Studio. But basically. The designer shows the form blank but it isn't. When I run the application I can see the form objects but I need to change add a new button and I can't.

I'm just hoping someone else has had this issue before and knows how to fix it.

Here are some screenshots:

[image: Visual Studio form]

[image: The Form when it's running]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! Basically, if you give InitializeComponent() a parameter then it won't load the form correctly in the designer.

Hope this helps someone out as this was driving me nuts!

Thanks.

Comment: if someone is going to down vote this, can you at least give an explanation?

Comment: this worked for me. I had changed the name of my Initialize() back to InitializeComponent() and it fixed it.